# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
package com.harshs.whatstheweather;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText cityName;
  TextView resultTextView;

  public void findWeather(View view) {

    Log.i("Button", cityName.getText().toString());

    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(cityName.getWindowToken(), 0);

    try {

      Weather task = new Weather();

      String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

      task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedURL + "&appid=ecd9af9d7b34407890a8b4096b6b90e2");

    } catch (Throwable e) {

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find the Weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }
  }

  class Weather extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {

      String result = "";

      URL url;

      HttpURLConnection connection;

      try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( in );

        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {

          char current = (char) data;
          result += current;

          data = reader.read();
        }
        return result;

      } catch (Throwable e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find the Weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      try {

        String mess = "";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

          JSONObject jSonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

          String main = "";
          String description = "";


          main = jSonPart.getString("main");
          description = jSonPart.getString("description");

          if (main != "" && description != "'") {

            mess += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";
          }
        }
        if (mess != "") {

          resultTextView.setText(mess);

        } else {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find the Weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }

      } catch (JSONException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find the Weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

      }

    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cityName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);


  }
}
```

I have this app that I'm building but the catch statements are not working. Whenever there is an exception the app crashes and the following error appears in the logs, and I don't know why. Please do help!

Here is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                               Process: com.harshs.whatstheweather, PID: 11019
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:346)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:101)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:260)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.harshs.whatstheweather.MainActivity$Weather.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.harshs.whatstheweather.MainActivity$Weather.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:52)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Please tell me what the error means.

Answer (score 2):

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

You should do more debugging to know what is the root cause of the error. Usually you can find the `caused by` line in the log/stack trace, thus you can know which part of your code are causing the error and fix that.

I think the error here is you are trying to make a Toast in `doInBackground()` method. Try to remove that, and capture the exception/error in `onPostExecute()` instead, and make/show Toast from there. `doInBackground()` does not execute in UI thread. If you are wrapping the AsyncTask class as an inner class in an Activity, you can also try to call `runOnUiThread()` method and make/show Toast from there, too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tired that by making the toast in doInBackground() but it still does not work.